# SQLite query 2 tables into android cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have 2 tables i SQLite working with Android.

Table 1 = T1

```
_id = INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
name = TEXT NOT NULL
time = TEXT NOT NULL
```

Table 2 = T2

```
_id = INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
ref = TEXT NOT NULL
info = TEXT NOT NULL
```

IN QUERY This is a list from T1 and works fine

```
String orderBy =  DBhelper.time + " ASC";
String[] columns = new String[]{ DBhelper._id, DBhelper.name, DBhelper.time};
Cursor c = db.query(true, DBhelper.T1, columns, null, null, null, null, orderBy, null, null);
```

Now I want to add in a lookup to table 2 in the query, like old fashioned:

```
SELECT T1._id, T1.name, T1.time, T2.info FROM T1, T2 WHERE T2.ref = T1._id;
```

Mind you: T1._id is integer and T2.ref is string.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're starting with a raw SQL query, the easiest way to use it is with [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29):

```java
String sql = "SELECT T1._id, T1.name, T1.time, T2.info FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T2.ref = T1._id";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

The not-so-easy way would be to use [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html), but this is useful mostly for content providers that need to safely handle SQL snippets from potentially malicious third party apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But now I got the problem using SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                MyActivity.this, R.layout.view_mylist, cursor, from, to, 1); as I can not refer to columns in from.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button. But you probably want to look at [How do you select from multiple tables in sqlite in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25098939/11654)